Can $2^n = 111\ldots112?$
I know that $2^n$ cannot $ = 1000\ldots002:$ because $3\mid 1000\ldots002$ but $3 \nmid\ 2^n.$
Also,  $2^n$ cannot $ = 1111\ldots110:$ because $5\mid 1111\ldots110$ but $5 \nmid\ 2^n.$
Are there any number theory arguments for why $2^n \neq 111\ldots112?$

There is no solution to $2^n \equiv 1112\pmod{10000}$ as per Wolfram Alpha. Need to see an easier solution to that, though (oh, it's there, see below).

By mod divisibility reduction $,2^n\mid a_n+b_n10^n !!\iff! 2^n\mid a_n,,$  Here it fails first for $,a_4 = 1112\ \ $

It seems that $16\nmid1112$, so $2^n$ cannot have this form for large $n$.

Ah, this is already be observed by the comment above~

It beat you by nine seconds, so I wouldn't take that as having priority. That said, this is pretty thin as an answer---it would help to spell out the point more to avoid this being marked as "should be a comment". (In particular, why is this objection sufficient to prevent larger cases?)

I don't get it. Why does  $16\nmid1112$ mean that $2^n$ cannot have this form for large $n$?

Ooooh, $16 \nmid 1112 \implies 16\nmid 1112 + 10000,$ because $16\mid 10000.$ And so on for larger $n$.

@Semiclassical I post this as an answer since I don't get enough score to post a comment (before I post this answer)...

\begin{align*}
111\ldots 112&=1+\sum_{k=0}^m 10^k =1+\dfrac{10^{m+1}-1}{10-1}=\dfrac{10^{m+1}+8}{9}=2^n\\[12pt]
9\cdot2^n&=2^3(1+2^{m-2}5^{m+1})\\[12pt]
9\cdot 2^{n-3}&=1+2^{m-2}5^{m+1}
\end{align*}
The RHS is odd for $m>2$ and the LHS is even for $n>3$ which rules out these cases. The remaining cases are $n\in \{0,1,2,3\}$ or $2^n\in \{1,2,4,8\}$ that are all of a different pattern, except $n=1$. $m\in \{0,1,2\}$ means $111\ldots 112\in \{2,12,112\}.$ Therefore
$$
2^1=2
$$
is the only solution.

My cost for typing slowly and being wordy.... should I delete my answer as you beat me by a few minutes?

@fleablood I have a trick. My keyboard is loaded with 67 LaTeX shortcuts, an AHK script. E.g. I type Alt+d and get \dfrac{}{} with the cursor placed within the first bracket.

... and I have a tendency to got into wordiness and to think and rethink "am I explaining this in the most simple and explanatory method"

Well  $N = \underbrace{111....1}_{k-2}2 = \underbrace{1111....11}_{k-1} + 1= \frac {10^k-1}9 +1$ so if this equal to $2^n$ then $9N= 9\cdot 2^n =(10^k-1) + 9= 10^k + 8$.
If we assume that $n$ and $k$ are both at least $3$ was can divide by $8$ to get
$\frac {9\cdot 2^n}8=\frac {9N}8\implies$
$9\cdot 2^{n-3}  =\frac {10^k+8}8 = \frac {10^k}8 + 1=2^{k-3}\cdot 5^k + 1$ which is odd if $k> 3$.
We can rule out that if $k=3$ then $N=12$ is no a power of $2$.  So if any $N$ is a power of $2$ we must have $9\cdot 2^{n-3}$ is odd which mean we must have $n=3$.  But $2^3 = 8$ is not any $N$ of the form $1111....1$.
.....
Or to put it in a naive but more hands on way:
$2^n = 11111.....1112 \iff$
$2^n = 11111.....1111 + 1\iff$
$9\cdot 2^n = 99999....9999 + 9 \iff$
$9\cdot 2^n = 100000....0000 + 8 \iff$
$9\cdot 2^{n-3} = 100000...0\times \frac{1000}8 + 1\iff$
$9\cdot 2^{n-3} = 100000...0\times 125 + 1$
But LHS is odd and right hand side is even except for small values of $n$ and/or small numbers of ones and those cases can be easily checked.
